# Want to read JSON file strings (multiple values) in perl

Tags: json, perl

Following is my json file (demo.json)

```
 [
  {
     "Directory" : "/opt/gehc/abc/root/mr_csd/xxx/diag/",
     "Files" : [ "abc.html","xyz.html", 
                "mnp.html"],
     "Permission" : 555
  }
 ]
```

i want to read each files in "Files" one by one which lies in "Directory", and change its "Permissions"

Following is the code i have started, Pls Help :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON;
my $filename = 'demo.json';

my $data;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh, '<', $filename;
    $data = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}

my $result = decode_json( $data );

for my $report ( @{$result} ) {
```

Comment: Your JSON file is an array of hashes (actually only a single hash here, so maybe you could use a simple hash instead?). Try `@{ $result->[0]{Files} }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your own code, you can easily de-reference the json-structure to simpler structures:

```
my @files = @{ $result->[0]{Files} };
my $perm = $result->[0]{Permission};

print Dumper \@files, $perm;
```

Which will print:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'abc.html',
          'xyz.html',
          'mnp.html'
        ];
$VAR2 = 555;
```

Then you can loop over the files with a simple for loop:

```
for my $file (@files) { ...
```

And [`chmod`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod) files as necessary. Though you may have to prepare the number `555` to be an octal, as described in the documentation.

And if you have several levels of this array that you call "reports", you can loop over them like so:

```
for my $report (@{ $result }) {
    my @files = @{ $report->{Files} };
    my $perm = $report->{Permission};
    print Dumper \@files, $perm;
}
```